Using R, list and access individual files on an ownCloud public folder
I have a public folder on ownCloud containing over 5,000 files. I need to access each individually in R (what all my collaborators use), but I don't have an individual sharing token. I would like to list.files in the directory and then apply through that. This answer did not work for me, throwing the error:

Error: [rast] file does not exist:
https://owncloud.gwdg.de/remote.php/dav/public-files/JRXVRDvnWwntQbO/u_component_of_wind_2023_10_1.nc
In addition: Warning message:
In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module,
fields$.pointer, ...) :
GDAL Error 1: An error occurred while
creating a virtual connection to the DAP server:Error while reading
the URL:
https://owncloud.gwdg.de/remote.php/dav/public-files/JRXVRDvnWwntQbO/u_component_of_wind_2023_10_1.nc.ver.
The OPeNDAP server returned the following message:
Not Found: The data
source or server could not be found.
Often this means that the OPeNDAP server is missing or needs attention.
Please contact the server administrator.

but when I make just one file share-able, I can access it without a problem:
rast("https://owncloud.gwdg.de/index.php/s/Oj2chbdlryN1vXR/download")

How can I use R to download each file in a shared ownCloud folder?

Maybe it's zipped. Already tried sth like httr::GET(base_url, httr::write_disk(temp_file)) |> unzip(temp_file, exdir=dest_dir)?

I had not tried. Using: httr::GET("https://owncloud.gwdg.de/remote.php/dav/public-files/JRXVRDvnWwntQbO", httr::write_disk(temp_path)) |>
unzip(temp_path, exdir=dest_dir)
is returning "invalid zip name argument".
